# Objective-C: Refreshing FrontmostApplication

Tags: objective-c, nsrunningapplication

I wrote this little program which is supposed to print the current frontmost application twice, with a 3-second break in between.

```
void printFrontmostApp() {
    NSRunningApplication *frontmostApplication = [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace].frontmostApplication;
    NSLog(@"%@",frontmostApplication);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        printFrontmostApp();
        sleep(3);
        printFrontmostApp();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I ran this program, I realised that frontmostApplication is not refreshed when it is called the second time. I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32533525/nsworkspaces-frontmostapplication-doesnt-change-after-initial-use). But I still have two questions:

1) I want to know *why* the frontmostApplication is not updated.

2) How do I force it to refresh every time I call it? I don't want to receive a notification every time the frontmost application deactivates, because it is a little inefficient for my purposes.

**Edit:**
Just to be crystal clear, let's suppose the time now is 10:00:00. I call printFrontmostApp, and it prints "Xcode" to the console, because Xcode is the current frontmost app. Then the program sleeps for 3 seconds. At 10:00:01, I opened another app, say TextEdit. At 10:00:03, my program calls printFrontmostApp for the second time. I expect it to print "TextEdit", which is the current frontmost application. But it prints "Xcode" instead. I can't understand this behaviour.

Can someone please explain what happens at 10:00:03? The function seems to "remember" the value of frontmostApplication at 10:00:00 and retains it when it is called the second time. I thought that any memory will be released once it goes out of scope, so why is this happening?

And how do I get my program to get the frontmost app at 10:00:03? I can get the frontmost app at 10:00:00, I should be able to do the same 3 seconds later right?

Comment: sleep(3) is 3 seconds or 3 milliseconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for `-[NSWorkspace runningApplications]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/runningApplications) — not the method you're using, but related — says:

> Similar to the `NSRunningApplication` class’s properties, this property will only change when the main run loop is run in a common mode. Instead of polling, use key-value observing to be notified of changes to this array property.

From the [`NSRunningApplication` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSRunningApplication_Class/index.html):

> Properties that vary over time are inherently race-prone. For example, a hidden app may unhide itself at any time. To ameliorate this, properties persist until the next turn of the main run loop in a common mode. For example, if you repeatedly poll an unhidden app for its hidden property without allowing the run loop to run, it will continue to return `NO`, even if the app hides, until the next turn of the run loop.

It's a near certainty that the same principle applies to `-frontmostApplication` even though the documentation doesn't say so explicitly. You will never get different results by polling without allowing the run loop to run.

Comment: What is a run loop? Can I manually run a run loop to trigger changes to NSRuningApplication's properties?

Comment: Here is Apple's [documentation of run loops](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html). You can run the run loop manually, although if you're writing an application there's usually no need. Note that both `NSWorkspace` and `NSRunningApplication` are part of AppKit, not Foundation, so using them as part of an application is the most natural fit, although it's not required.

Answer (score 1):

For 1) the answer is the same described in the question you have linked: You have to observe this notification, that tells you when a new application was activated:

`NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification`

About 2) You have different observers for activation and deactivation like:

`NSWorkspaceDidDeactivateApplicationNotification`

So your are not going to observe notifications that you are not registered, please take a look at [NSWorkspace Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/#//apple_ref/c/data/NSWorkspaceWillLaunchApplicationNotification) for a comprehensive list.

Otherwise, please define your question about refreshing/polling (that I think it's not a good idea anyways).